# Missed my private signing file for Android

Tags: android, keystore

I made an Android App and posted it in Android market, and now I'm made some updates on my Apps and trying to give a next version of the same app. The problem is I missed my KeyStore file I generated previously. But I'm having my old vesion APK file. Now I'm not able to upload the next version, the developer console says

```
The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version.
```

as error. May I get any help to make new version for my android app now..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no way of retrieving a lost signing key. What you can do is get a new one, pull your app from the market, and upload your update using a different package name.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, as far as i know you are not allowed to update your application now.

To update existing application on market, you must have that KeyStore file and also remember the password.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to unpublish the old apk and publish a new apk signed using a new keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have the previously used key store file with you

As per the documentation available on [developer.andoird.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketupgrade) you must do the followings

> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have
>   incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes
>   in the  element of the manifest file. Also, the package name
>   must be the same as the existing version **and the .apk file must be
>   signed with the same private key**. If the package name and signing
>   certificate do not match those of the existing version, Google Play
>   will consider it a new application, publish it as such, and will not
>   offer it to existing users as an update.